# How to migrate data from local on-premises HDFS to Azure storage

Tags: azure, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight, hdp

I want to move the data from my local on-premises HDFS server to my Azure HDinsight cluster.

I tried distcp command but it does not understand the data lake storage path.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps for Connecting on-premise Hadoop to ADLS:**

**Step1:** Create the Azure Data Lake Store account.

**Step2:** Create the identity to access Azure Data Lake Store.

**Step3:** Modify the core-site.xml in your on-premise Hadoop cluster.

**Step4:** Test connectivity to Azure Data Lake Store from on-premise Hadoop.

**Step5:** Use DistCp to transfer the data from on-premise Hadoop to Azure Data Lake Store.

**Syntax:** `hadoop distcp <HDFS_Path> <ADLS_PATH>`

Example: `hadoop distcp README.txt adl://mydatalakename.azuredatakestore.net/`

For more details, refer "[Connecting On-premise Hadoop to Azure Data Lake Store](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Connecting-On-premises-Hadoop-to-Azure-Data-Lake-Store)" and [Migrate on-premise Apache Hadoop cluster to Azure HDInsight - data migration best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-on-premises-migration-best-practices-data-migration).

Hope this helps.